# updating record in one table and reflecting the change in another

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

i am a newbie working on developing a website. i am using flask, flask-admin, and flask-sqlalchemy. in my setup i have two tables named wings and submenuitem. i am trying to add an entry in submenuitem when a new entry is made in wings. similarly, if a entry is edited, i want that the corresponding entry in submenuitem is also updated.

currently, my code is as follows which allow me to make an entry under submenuitem.

```
def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if is_created:
                submenu = submenuitem(title=form.name.data, url="wings")
                db.session.add(submenu)
                db.session.commit()
        else:
                submenu = submenuitem.query.filter_by(title=model.name).first()
                if submenu:
                    submenu.title = model.name
                    db.session.commit()
```

however, when using flask-admin to edit my entries under wing, new entry is made under submenuitem while the existing entry is not updated. also, the model.name and form.name.data points to new name entered while the entry in submenuitem exists with previous name.